# Does it make sense to host movies from a home LAMP server SQL database?

Tags: performance, installation, lamp, host, movies

First off, my apologies if the concept of this question makes no sense, as I am attempting to create my first SQL database.

-Does it make sense to host movies from a home LAMP server SQL database?
-If I decide to host videos from an SQL database via my Ubuntu 12.04 LAMP server, will I have advantages in performance? 
-Will that include wireless/wired streaming over an Airport Extreme router (or in other words, over a network)?

The alternative would be a file share. I am aiming to learn some basic SQL setup and administration; I thought this might be an interesting and educational way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean store the movies as binary blobs in the database?! Absolutely not. I often wonder why people even store images in their databases. Do not do this, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your mention of images re-enforces the concept, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by researching how various home media solutions solve this problem.  Each has differing upsides and downsides.  Some focus on indexing and adding metadata to shared network drives then provide a browsing interface to it.  Others wholly encapsulate the media store and provide the media directly--sometimes by faking a file share which in reality is backed by the database.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of video over network depends on the performance of your main server. Now if you want to host the videos your server should be very fast and reliable.

It's advisable to use LAMP Server if used on LAN Network.

But if you are planning for later modification in terms of users then I would suggest that you go with the alternative.